# React Native Maps Prevent focus when marker is clicked

Tags: react-native, android-mapview

is there a way to disable the **marker focus** when it is clicked? Like I want the map view to stay as it is when I click a marker. Right now, if I click any marker the map view automatically adjust focusing on that marker. Is there a way to disable it? Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

As jasongaare states in https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/199#issuecomment-330901293, there is a `moveOnMarkerPress` property for the MapView component.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to make it possible for now is to do the LiteMode

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/LiteMapView.js

So far it works just fine, it does not focus anymore to the pressed Map Mark.